# React Router error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

hey guys having trouble with react-router, i keep getting this unexpected token you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type on the line with `<Router history={browserHistory}>`. im not sure what is going on here any help would be appreciated!

thanks

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Products from './Products'
import Home from './Home'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Home} />
   <Route path="/" component={Products} />
  </Router>, document.getElementById('mount')
 );
});
```

webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'),
  entry: [
   './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
   filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
   loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
     },
    ],
  },
     resolve: {
       root: [
       path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
     ],
    },
  };
  module.exports = config;
```

.babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Comment: could you share your webpack.config?

Comment: just added those files @SivadassN

Comment: @jordan can you try **loader: 'babel-loader'**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a React Router issue but instead is an issue with your JSX transpilation. Check your webpack.config.js file or your .babelrc file.